# How to return APK file with ServiceStack

Tags: asp.net, servicestack

Basically I would love to hit path on my server like http://myserver.com/files/androidapp.apk and have server serve that file without requiring me to write the service.

Since .apk is not "standard" mime type in plain ASP.NET I could do that by adding this in web.config:

```
<staticContent>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".apk" mimeType="application/vnd.android.package-archive" />
</staticContent>
```

But this doesn't work with ServiceStack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an unknown extension to ServiceStack's whitelist with:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig { 
    AllowFileExtensions = { "apk" },
});
```

Which will allow ServiceStack to serve files with that extension.

You can then specify what MimeType it should use with:

```
MimeTypes.ExtensionMimeTypes["apk"] = "application/vnd.android.package-archive";
```